# Finding brief repeated patterns in a time series

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition, unsupervised-learning

Suppose I have a series of events, each of which is an element of {-1, 0 1} with a known distribution. Events happen in approximately continuous time. My dependent variable is the sum of the series.

The series appears to be a random walk, perhaps with drift. However, an angel has appeared to me in a dream, or maybe the ghost of Karl Pearson, and told me that there are rare unobservable events that affect the observable events in a uniform way. However, the angel did not tell me what the pattern was, only that it is rare and of short duration relative to the length of the series.

Most of the statistics I have learned is econometrics, i.e. one form or another of regression model, and does not seem to apply to finding patterns in data which are not constant functional relationships between variables or between variables and time. Is there one or more commonly used  technique for finding such patterns? Would this fall under the heading of unsupervised learning?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem exactly, but your title and first line seem might indicate you are looking for repeated sub-sequences in a longer sequence whose elements are drawn from a small "alphabet"? (e.g. many [lossless compression algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless) essentially do this)

Comment: define "uniform way"

Comment: @andrewH Pls clarify. If the event log is public, why do you care about your dependent variable?

Comment: @GeoMatt22, that is roughly correct, except there may be noise in the pattern. And the consistency might be in the shape, and not the length -- such as a sequence of 1's followed by a sequence of negative 1's.

Comment: @Taylor Well, I am actually hoping that the algorithm will define what I mean by "in a uniform way" without additional input from me. But the basic situation is that changes can only occur in this discrete way, driven mainly by noise, but with infrequent causal blips added, which I envision as a series of wavelets, consistent in shape but perhaps not in duration. Although if I had an algorithm that could find these infrequent blips only for constant duration that would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @horaceT I can only observe the noise plus the superimposed signal. I want to find the times when the signal is occurring, although given the noise, I would expect some false negatives and positives.